# Xcode and OpenCV

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am trying to compile a C++ project that uses OpenCV in Xcode 6.2. I have downloaded OpenCV and the header and library files and setting as follow:
Header Search Path: /usr/local/include/opencv2**
Library Search Path:/usr/local/lib
and opencv is truly in this Path,but I get error:

---

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
/Users/radio_lee/Desktop/project/OpenCV/OpenCV/main.cpp:1:10: 'cv.h' file not found

---

when I change the Header Search Path and Library Search Path like that:
Header Search Path: 
/usr/local/include/opencv2**  and /usr/local/include/opencv
Library Search Path:/usr/local/lib

another error:

---

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:63:10: 'opencv2/core/core_c.h' file not found

/Users/radio_lee/Desktop/project/OpenCV/OpenCV/main.cpp:1:10: In file included from /Users/radio_lee/Desktop/project/OpenCV/OpenCV/main.cpp:1:

---

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is a Private Framework,Since it is a Private Framework, it must be copied to the Frameworks/ directory of an Application Bundle, which means, it is useless for plain unix console applications.
We can see the detail in this web site :http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html#table-of-content-introduction

This folder contains toolchains and additional files that are needed for cross compilation.
For more information see introduction tutorials for target platform in documentation.